# What is the best way to add a main menu before game activity starts?

Tags: android, menu

I'm working on a 2d game and I want to add a main menu. Currently when i run my code my main activity starts the game loop.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set fullscreen
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Set No Title
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


    this.setContentView(new GameSurface(this));
}
```

This is my code and my intend is to bind the setContentView() to a play button in my menu. What is the best way to implement my menu, setting it as different activity and loading it on create, then via intent to set the loading of the GameSurface as another activity or there is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your MainActivity the main menu, and create separate GameActivity.
For example:

your main_activity.xml (menu):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"> <!-- define your custom background, f.e. html animation or picture -->

<Button
        android:id="@+id/start_game"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start the game"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exit"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
```

your MainActivity (you can play music or do other useful actions if you want):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button startGame;
private Button settings;
private Button exit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    startGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_game);
    startGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent game = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
            startActivity(game);
        }
    });

    settings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings);
    settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent game = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class); 
            startActivity(game);
        }
    });

    exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
    exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}
}
```

And your GameActivity:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set fullscreen
    this.getWindow().setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Set No Title
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


    this.setContentView(new GameSurface(this));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!